# Adding voltage from same power supply

Tags: voltage, raspberry-pi

[image]

I am a programmer but new to electronics and trying to combine voltage two DC voltages. This works when I use two separate batteries i.e. I can use two 9v batteries and connect them in series to get total of 18V power supply.

However when I try to do the same using the two 5V output from the power supply as in [Solderless Breadboard with Power and I/O Breakout Board](https://www.jaycar.com.au/solderless-breadboard-with-power-and-i-o-breakout-board/p/PB8819). It just stops working. What I did is connect positive from the 1st 5V output to negative of 2nd 5V output, and as soon as I do that the power supply stops working (may be it shorts). Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong? and if it is not possible then why?

Comment: Which power input are you using, the jack or the USB?

Comment: I am using two 5V jacks. one on right side and the one on left side.

Comment: You really need to show how you have this hooked up, the question is sort of unclear. Maybe post a picture.

Comment: Sure. working on it. give me 10 mins

Comment: Added image of my breadboard.

Comment: It looks highly likely that input and output share a common ground, so you're shorting them out by trying to connect them in series.

Comment: Are the two 5v power suppies you are stacking *electrically isolated* from each other? Super duper important that they are...

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a 5V and 3.3V voltage regulator on your module. It means that both 5V power supplies on either side of the module are the output of the 5V regulator (same for 3.3V power jacks). So you cannot connect them in series to get 10V.

Comment: In layman terms, you mean that even thought both says 5V each, they both are internally connected (and not two separate/isolated ) and hence it is shorting ? If so, will it work if I replace this with another power supply providing two  isolated outputs ?

Comment: @user1589040 you would need two of those breadboards to do what you want. Though even that will not work if you use the USB ports from the same source.

Comment: @Trevor_G: You mean I will need two separate power supply units as show in the image on same breadboard OR I can sum the two 5V outputs of one power supply using two separate breadboards ? Sorry, if these r silly questions.

Comment: @user1589040 I mean if you had two breadboards each powered from it's own wallwart, you could hook them up and put the rails in series as you imagine. Though not sure the breadboard connections will allow you to fudge that.

Comment: Yes. got it....

Comment: @user1589040 be aware though, that is likely to be 5V on top of 5V, not really +-5V if that is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Trevor_G. It's +-5V if he pegs neutral in the middle... Gah, did I say neutral? Too long in diy.se...  I meant GND.  Not to be confused with safety earthing.

Comment: @Harper ya sort of, though the -5V high side will not sink anything. Not like a battery would.

Answer (score 0):

There is one 5V regulator and one 3V regulator on this module (the two identical parts with 3 pins on the left and one large pin on the right, between the yellow jumper terminals). So you are basicaly shorting the 5V output. You can't even put in serie the 5V with the 3V, because they are regulators on a same power supply, not power supplies themselves. I'm not sure it's even possible to put in serie from separate PSUs with these regulators... because they will regulate to 5V or 3V.